# Cant call Imagebutton in a OnCommand function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this in ASP.NET in VS
I have image button in repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="Imagebutton2" runat="server"  CssClass="choicebutton" ImageUrl='<%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "answer" )%>' CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "question" )%>' CommandName='<%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "answer" )%>'    OnCommand="checkAnswer"  />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and I want to change border color of image button when it is false

```
public void checkAnswer(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

    string trueanswer = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    string urlanswer = e.CommandName.ToString();
    if (urlanswer == q_image)
    {
    }
    else
    {
      // Imagebutoon2 doesnt exist in current context why?
      Imagebutton2.BorderColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ItemDataBound` for this task:

```
protected void RepeaterImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
     RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
     if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
     {
         Imagebutton  Imagebutton2= (Imagebutton)item.FindControl("Imagebutton2");

         string trueanswer = Imagebutton.CommandArgument.ToString();
         string urlanswer = Imagebutton.CommandName.ToString();

         if (urlanswer == q_image)
         {
         }
         else
         {
            // Imagebutoon2 doesnt exist in current context why?
            Imagebutton2.BorderColor = Color.Red;

         }

    }
}
```

Do not forget to add this to the repeater server tag:  `OnItemDataBound="RepeaterImages_ItemDataBound"`

**UPDATE**

If you want this happen when imagebutton is clicked, then it is even more simple. You can use `sender` to access the imagebutton clicked:

```
 public void checkAnswer(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
 {
       ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;

       string trueanswer = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
       string urlanswer = e.CommandName.ToString();
       if (urlanswer == q_image)
       {
       }
       else
       {
          // Imagebutoon2 doesnt exist in current context why?
          btn.BorderColor = Color.Red;

       }
  }
```

Comment: First of all thank very much for helping me with your precious time.But what i want is check for every image true or false(with argument and name) so i call oncommand for every image(it happen when client click).

Comment: @user3397383 you mean when these images are clicked, you want to change their border? not when the repeater is first generated?

Comment: @ erkaner yeah, when clicked images check the value (name )of them and chacnge border to green or red

Comment: @user3397383 I am glad it worked! it would be great if you can mark this post as the correct answer!